# FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" using simple docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I was having issues connecting to my PG database in my compose file.  I finally eliminated all other factors and made this bare-bones compose file:

```
version: '2.1'
services:

  database:
    image: postgres:9.5.6
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secretpass
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

I then started it up with this command:

```
docker-compose --file docker-compose.pg.yml up --build
```

and it seemed to start ok:

```
Starting app_database_1 ... 
Starting app_database_1 ... done
Attaching to app_database_1
database_1  | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-09-22 18:48:55 UTC
database_1  | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
database_1  | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
database_1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

Then from another shell, tried to connect with this command:

```
psql postgresql://postgres:secretpass@0.0.0.0
```

And got this output on my first shell where the compose was run:

```
database_1  | FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
database_1  | DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5"
```

I have also tried to connect from another container running 
Rails defined in the compose file and get the same error.  I always end up with an authentication error.  What am I missing?

Comment: When you say shell, the shell was inside the docker container or on the docker host?

Comment: Turns out there was something wrong with my Docker process.  I restarted it and all worked fine.